# Solve unknown error when using a range to fill in value for a group of textboxes on a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I hoped would fill the values of the textboxes from a range.  I first need to search for the column in a data sheet based on the value of a specific cell of another sheet.  I need to then use the data in that column to fill the values of the textboxes.  I thought I had worked it out but have received the following error I can't seem to figure out why.  below is screenshot of the error and my code.  Thank you.

Edit:  I tried to upload screenshot but it didn't seem to work.  The error is "Runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim unit As Range
With Range("A1:G1")
 Set unit = .Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shift Report").Range("A1"), 
   LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim cn As Long
cn = unit.column
Dim tbcounter As Long
tbcounter = 1
Dim rw As Long
For rw = 2 To 30
    If .Range(cn & rw).Value <> "" And tbcounter <= 20 Then
        Me.Controls("Textbox" & tbcounter).Text = .Range(cn & rw).Value
        tbcounter = tbcounter + 1
    End If
Next rw
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `cn` and `rw` are long integer so `.Range(cn & rw).Value` should be `.Cells(rw,cn).value`

Comment: This was the problem.  Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given an answer and am trying to post it as answered. Here is the updated code that works.  I was using .range when it should have been .cells

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim unit As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:G1")
 Set unit = .Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shift Report").Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Dim cn As Long
cn = unit.column
Dim tbcounter As Long
tbcounter = 1
Dim rw As Long
For rw = 2 To 30
    If .Cells(rw, cn).Value <> "" And tbcounter <= 20 Then
        Me.Controls("Textbox" & tbcounter).Text = .Cells(rw, cn).Value
        tbcounter = tbcounter + 1
    End If
Next rw
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the reasons why your previous code didn't work.

Comment: I was referencing .range when it should have been .cells

Comment: Could you please update the answer with this info?